# How to use xarray concat function to store the mean of daily temperature data inside of a loop?

Tags: python, concatenation, python-xarray, weather

I have a netcdf file with multiple years of gridded daily tmax data. I am trying to find the average daily maximum temperature for each day of the year (i.e. average June 1 temp using every June 1 in the data set and then doing the same for every other day of the year). I have a loop that is doing this but am struggling to figure out how to store the data. I am trying to use xarray concat function but when I do this am ending up with only one day of tmax. My final data array should be time: 366 y: 277 x: 349 but instead I am getting no time, only y: 277 x: 349

```
for month, day in zip(months[0:366],days[0:366]):
    which_days=(months==month) & (days==day)
    month_day_mean=Tmax[which_days].mean("time")
    climate_normal=xr.concat(month_day_mean,dim='air')
```

Xarray is new to me and I am not sure how the concat function works. Am I setting this up wrong?

Comment: I changed the last line of code to: climate_normal=xr.concat([month_day_mean],dim='time') but am still only getting a data array with time: 1

Comment: I think the problem is that 'climate_normal' will always be just the last 'month_day_mean'. Try collecting all 'month_day_mean' in a list first and then use xr.concat after the loop. That is:

climate_dummy = []
for month, day in zip(months[0:366],days[0:366]):
    which_days=(months==month) & (days==day)
    month_day_mean=Tmax[which_days].mean("time")
    climate_dummy.append(month_day_mean)

climate_normal = xr.concat(climate_dummy,dim='air')

This is untested.

Comment: After reading more closely what you would like to achieve have a look at the 'groupby' command. It does what you want without a loop.

Try:
climate_normal = Tmax.groupby('time.dayofyear').mean()

Have a look at: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/time-series.html towards the bottom of the webpage.